# Missing threads in a Java thread dump

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I use `ThreadMXBean` to report a list of threads using `dumpAllThreads(true, true)`:

```
ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
for (ThreadInfo info : bean.dumpAllThreads(true, true)) {
    writer.append(ThreadInfos.toStringFull(info));
}
```

However, some of the threads in the dump don't appear to exist, and worse they appear to own monitors!:

```
"pool-24-thread-16" Id=99 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@a8bb29 owned by "ForkJoinPool-2-worker-13" Id=114
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@a8bb29
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(Unknown Source)
```

In this example, `ForkJoinPool-2-worker-13` is not listed in the thread dump, so it's difficult to see how it has grabbed `ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@a8bb29`.

I must be making some silly mistake! How do I find how these threads have taken these locks?

Comment: Have you launched your code several times consecutively? You may simply have outdated thread info which could be fixed in the next calls

Comment: Assume you mean in the same VM? Doesn't `dumpAllThreads` get fresh data each time? I guess I don't understand how a thread can be referenced as owning a lock, when the thread doesn't appear to exist anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your approach does not work. I expected it to work. However, try an alternative approach if you're using OpenJDK or Oracle JRE.

```
kill -3 <pid of java>
```

This will dump all the threads and their locks to the java process's standard out. (It also dump the object histogram but you can ignore that.)